# accented characters not displayed correctly on a web site

Tags: html, fonts, adobe, typekit, muse

I have a strange issue where accented characters (central european) are not shown correctly. The web site was created in Adobe Muse, and the fonts are Museo Slab and Open Sans (from Typekit) which should contain accented characters and they appear correctly on Typekit's website and on typetester.org as well.

I have checked the code but not found anything what might be causing the issue.

The website (work in progress) is at http://festivalzvsk.businesscatalyst.com/

thanks,
Michael

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right [character set](https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/language-support-subsetting.html)? I don't think the default subset contains Central European characters.

Comment: it was the subsetting within Muse - the option 'default subset' in File > Site Properties was not using the full character set, so when switched to "All' it worked. Many thanks for pointing me to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

it was the font subsetting option within Muse - the option 'default subset' in File > Site Properties was not using the full character set (default subsetting is the default option), so when switched to "All' it worked. Many thanks for pointing me to right direction.